# Responsabilidade de service e repository

Tags: mvc, design-pattern, services, repository

Pessoal gostaria de saber de quem usa **design-pattern de service e repository**, como seria uma estrutura básica de arquitetura, ou seja o que o service pode ou não fazer, e quais são as responsabilidades do repository. Atualmente estou utilizando o seguinte padrão, **View, Model(utilizo Doctrine), Controller, service, repository** , e gostaria de saber qual seria a maneira mais correta do fluxo de dados e a responsabilidade de cada um. Alguém poderia me ajudar a esclarecer esta duvida ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440096/difference-between-repository-and-service

Comment: Essa reposta é para que cair aqui de paraquedas. Só para constar, há um repositório com um exemplo simples, que pode auxiliar, tente implementar: https://github.com/jsafe00/laravel-service-repository/